# How to make ccache exclude checking for specific files

Tags: ccache

I used cmake to build a c++ project, but ccache didn't hit when I switched the git branch back.
How do I avoid recompiling because the current code is exactly the same as before.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you did exactly? Because it seems to me like Ccache should have returned cache hits after all. Did you change any CMake options? Also, how does your question title relate to all of this?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis I just switch the git branch and didn't change anything. I expect no recompilation to be triggered.